# Where does Bazel gets Selenium Webdriver atoms from?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, bazel

So I have a test automation framework based on Selenium(using it as a .dll).  What I'm trying to do is to add Selenium as a project to be able to debug through its code.

I see that in WebDriver.csproj there's a line calling a cmd as a pre-build step

```
<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent" Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'">
    <Exec Command="call $(ProjectDir)WebDriver.csproj.prebuild.cmd $(ProjectDir)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PreBuildNonWindows" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent" Condition="'$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT'">
    <Exec Command="$(ProjectDir)WebDriver.csproj.prebuild.sh $(ProjectDir)" />
  </Target>
```

This cmd runs some Bazel commands

```
@echo off
if not exist "%1..\..\..\bazel-bin\javascript\webdriver\atoms\get-attribute.js" (
  echo Building getAttribute atom
  pushd "%1..\..\.."
  bazel build //javascript/webdriver/atoms:get-attribute.js
  popd
)

if not exist  "%1..\..\..\bazel-bin\javascript\atoms\fragments\is-displayed.js" (
  echo Building isDisplayed atom
  pushd "%1..\..\.."
  bazel build //javascript/atoms/fragments:is-displayed.js
  popd
)

if not exist  "%1..\..\..\bazel-bin\javascript\atoms\fragments\find-elements.js" (
  echo Building findElements atom
  pushd "%1..\..\.."
  bazel build //javascript/atoms/fragments:find-elements.js
  popd
)
```

I was trying to install Bazel on my machine(which is running Windows Server 2016) but for some reason was not able even to get a version after installing. The message said it was not compatible with my Windows version.
So I decided to search for all the javascript files used in Selenium on the internet. I was able to find the majority of them except maybe several.
So my question is: is there any storage for Selenium js atoms or Bazel auto-generates them somehow?

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Just copy and paste and click the code button in the question editor. Images of code are too difficult to read.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Edited. Anything related to question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is the best solution but I've found missing atoms under

> ...\selenium-trunk\rb\lib\selenium\webdriver\atoms\

What I needed was just to rename them and place to the appropriate folder like so:

```
getAttribute.js=>get-attribute.js=>...\selenium-trunk\bazel-bin\javascript\webdriver\atoms\
isDisplayed.js=>is-displayed.js=>...\selenium-trunk\bazel-bin\javascript\atoms\fragments\
findElements.js=>find-elements.js=>...\selenium-trunk\bazel-bin\javascript\atoms\fragments\
```

The paths are where WebDriver.csproj searches for that files

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="$(ProjectDir)../../../bazel-bin/javascript/webdriver/atoms/get-attribute.js">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <LogicalName>get-attribute.js</LogicalName>
</EmbeddedResource>
<EmbeddedResource Include="$(ProjectDir)../../../bazel-bin/javascript/atoms/fragments/is-displayed.js">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <LogicalName>is-displayed.js</LogicalName>
</EmbeddedResource>
<EmbeddedResource Include="$(ProjectDir)../../../bazel-bin/javascript/atoms/fragments/find-elements.js">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <LogicalName>find-elements.js</LogicalName>
</EmbeddedResource>
```